# Add Web Reference in Visual Studio with Header

Tags: .net, visual-studio, magento2, soap-client

Let me describe my problem. I am trying to Add a Web Reference to Magento 2.x SOAP API.

In Magento 1.x we could just use the given soap service URL and generate the classes using the Visual Studio in-built UI tool "Add Service Reference > Advanced > Web Reference"

But in Magento 2.x the url needs a "Authorization" header to return the WSDL.

I tried hitting the API with the header using Postman and it returns the WSDL fine. But there are no option to include headers in the Visual Studio "Add Web Reference" dialog.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can quickly work around this by simply opening the downloaded WSDL saved to a local file. Just copy-and-paste the full file path to the Webservice URL input in VisualStudio.

Comment: WSDL and SOAP are both kinda obsolete - have you looked at using their REST web-services instead? (Note that the "Add web reference" functionality in VS is only for WSDL/SOAP and not REST)

Comment: @Filburt yes that is how we went ahead in the end

Comment: @Dai Yes we started off with Rest. But we were having serialization and deserialization issues.

Comment: @Dai If you really want to go all-new-fancy-pants looks like [gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) is the latest fad.

Comment: @Filburt gRPC only makes sense at-scale. While it's decades ahead of CORBA (literally, heh), the sheer simplicity of REST and its ease-of-use thanks to a plaintext, human-readable protocol (HTTP) makes it difficult to unseat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who stumbles upon this.
I followed the comment by @Filburt and did the following.

---

Generated the Admin Token Using Rest with Postman GET (ref. [Magento documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html))

1. Header : Content-Type - application/json
2. Body : {"username" : "my username","password" : "my password"}

---

Hit my required Individual [Magento SOAP APIs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/soap/bk-soap.html) with Postman GET Request.

Used Postman in-built Authorization > Bearer Token : got value from previous step

Then Saved the resulting XML locally with .wsdl extension

---

In Visual Studio used In-built "Add Service Reference" UI and imported the wsdl file.

All Services were generated successfully.